# Positioning objects on web page with css

Tags: html, css

If I create a button `<Button id="Button" text="Hey" />`, how would I go about positioning it on a web page wherever I wanted it to be and not just being wherever there is no content?

Answer (score 4):

Use [CSS positioning](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute positioning.

ex:

```
position:absolute; //Place wherever we want on the page
left-margin:10px; //Move right 10px
top-margin:20px; //Move down 20px
z-index:2; //Put on top of everything with z-index of 1 or 0
```

Comment: its just left:10px; top:20px is enough, positioning with the margin isn't a  proper way, thanks